# Calling function AFTER .ready() in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to call a JavaScript function after the `.ready()` function has executed?

I think there's something funny going on in some DOM structuring in my code, and I want to try calling `jquery.('reload')` on a section.  But I need to call it *AFTER* the `$(document).ready(function(){})` is called.

To clarify a bit more, I'm using jQuery's masonry, and I'm having an issue with the rendering of elements. It comes with a method '`reload`', and when called inside of `.ready()`, doesn't render correctly, but if done on say, a scroll event, it works fine.

Comment: To clarify, do you want this code to execute after all handlers for the `.ready` event have been run?

Comment: In what moment, specifically, do you want to call this function? And what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I believe so, my expectations are to trigger a function after everything in .ready() has executed.  Unless it doesn't 'execute'.  If I'm mistaking how it actually works, then forgive me, I assume once the javascript loads, .ready is triggered, executes, then is done with that `file.js` or `<script></script>`

Comment: I updated my OP to hopefully clear up my question.

Comment: How about triggering scroll event at the end of your ready function?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, I don't get your comment @craftsman, as the scroll even works fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your code to be executed **right after** `.ready()` is executed, you can use a `setTimeout` of `0` milliseconds.

```
$.ready(function(){

    setTimeout(myCoolFunction,0);
});
```

*This example will execute `myCoolFunction` as soon as possible after `.ready()` has occurrred.*

Answer (score 0):

What does it mean jquery.('reload')??
Maybe you can call it last in the $(document).ready(function(){})!

Comment: I wasn't clear enough, I meant jQuery's masonry plugin using the .('reload') method.  

My problem is that when I generate a series of 'boxes' using masonry in say a loop, it doesn't render them right, but when I generate them via scroll event, which I assume has nothing to do with .ready() they render correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) method. It's fired when every resource is loaded. [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) is as soon as the DOM is fully loaded.

EDIT: Just noticed, the [.load() shorthand is deprecated](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11733), use `$().bind("load", fn)` instead